# Signed measure absolutely continuous with respect to $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose $F$ is real-valued and integrable with respect to $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]^2$ and$$\int_0^{x_0} \int_0^{y_0} F(x, y)\,dy\,dx= 0$$for all $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ and $y_0 \in [0, 1]$. Does it follow that $F = 0$ almost everywhere?

---

> Define the following signed measure$$\nu(A) = \int_A F\,d\mu$$which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $d\mu = dx\,dy$ since $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A) = 0$.

**Question.** I still don't follow why the aforementioned signed measure is absolutely continuous with respect to $d\mu$. Is it anybody could elaborate as to why here?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\nu((0,x)\times(0,y)) = \int_{(0,x)\times(0,y)} F\ \mathsf d\mu=0 $$ for all $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$. For any open rectangle $(x,x')\times(y,y')\in[0,1]^2$, we have
$$(0,x')\times(0,y') = (0,x)\times (0,y)\ \cup\ (x,x')\times (y,y'),  $$ so that 
$$\nu\left((x,x')\times (y,y')\right) = \nu\left((0,x')\times(0,y')\right) - \nu\left((0,x)\times (0,y)\right)=0.  $$
By outer regularity of Lebesgue measure, if $A\subset[0,1]^2$ is measurable, there exists a sequence $\{(x_j,x_j')\times (y_j,y_j')\}$ of open rectangles such that $$A\subset\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (x_j,x_j')\times (y_j,y_j') $$ and $$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^n (x_j,x_j')\times (y_j,y_j')\right)\leqslant \mu(A)+\frac1n,\quad n=1,2,\ldots. $$
So if $\mu(A)=0$, let $A_j:=(x_j,x_j')\times (y_j,y_j')$ be a such sequence, then 
\begin{align}
\nu(A) &\leqslant \nu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_j\right)\\
&= \int_{\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_j} F\ \mathsf d\mu \\
&\leqslant \mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_j\right)\|F\|_1\\
&\leqslant \frac{\|F\|_1}n
\end{align}
for all positive integers $n$, and hence $\nu(A)=0$. Since $|F|\leqslant \|F\|_1$, it follows that $F=0$ almost everywhere.