# Why does $\nu(A) = 0$ for all Borel subsets of $[0, 1]^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose $F$ is real-valued and integrable with respect to $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]^2$ and$$\int_0^{x_0} \int_0^{y_0} F(x, y)\,dy\,dx= 0$$for all $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ and $y_0 \in [0, 1]$. Does it follow that $F = 0$ almost everywhere?

---

> Define the following signed measure
>   \begin{align}
> \nu(A) = \int_A F\ d\mu
> \end{align}
>   which one could check is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $d\mu=dxdy$ since $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A)=0$.
>
> Since $\nu(A) = 0$ on all rectangles of $[0, 1]^2$, then, by extension, we see that $\nu(A) = 0$ for all Borel subsets of $[0, 1]^2$, i.e. effectively $\nu$ is the zero measure.

I don't follow that $\nu(A) = 0$ for all Borel subsets of $[0, 1]^2$ here. Is it possible anybody could elaborate on why this is true?

Comment: This question was already asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959476/signed-measure-absolutely-continuous-with-respect-to-2-dimensional-lebesgue-me/1959610

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the collection of all subsets of $[0,1]^2$ that can be written as the finite union of rectangles in $[0,1]^2$. This is a ring, in the sense that it is closed under unions and intersections. Moreover, the $\sigma$-algebra it generates is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Notice that any set in $R$ can actually be written as the disjoint union of rectangles, and hence $X\in R\implies \nu(X) = 0$, since $\nu(A) = 0$ for all rectangles $A$. Caratheodory's extension theorem says that there is an extension of $\nu|_R$, the restriction of $\nu$ to $R$, to a measure $\nu^*$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but moreover, since $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $A$ (because it's, well, zero), the extension is unique.

Now, one way to extend $\nu|_R$ is by just setting $\nu^*(B) = 0$ for all $B$ Borel. Another way is by setting $\nu^*(B) = \nu(B)$ for all $B$ Borel. The extension theorem says that there is only one way to extend $\nu|_R$, so these extensions must be the same. i.e. $\nu(B) = \nu^*(B) = 0$ for all $B$ Borel.